# Regex to match alphanumeric character and ampersand(&)

Tags: regex

I need regex to search string for `alphanumeric, (, ), -, ., / and ampersand(&).`

Right now i m using this regex in client side validation

```
 [^A-Za-z0-9.)(/-\&]
```

**EDIT:**

I want to search my string for special characters `VAL.search(/[^A-Za-z0-9.)(/-\&]+/g)==-1`

Comment: You need to clarify what you want. In your question you say you want to match these characters `()-./&a-zA-Z0-9` and possibly are saying you actually want to match anything that is NOT these characters. Do you want to match `^`? Do you want to match `\`?

Comment: In jquery validation i want to search my string for alphanumeric & special chars other than (,.-/&) e.g. string like  "b&g (54.4kg/m)".If someone enter any special char other than specified above then my function will return false. my code to search string is VAL.search(/[^A-Za-z0-9.)(/-\&]+/g)==-1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Escape the backslash, put the dash at the end of the character class.

```
[^A-Za-z0-9.)(/\\&-]
```

Not sure why you included `^`, as this negates the character class.

Comment: should be escaping forward slash, not backslash. Also needs to escape dot and parenthesis

Comment: @Billy: No. The forward slash has no special meaning in regex, and even more so it has no special meaning in character classes.

Comment: include ^ because i want to search my string for special characters  VAL.search(/[^A-Za-z0-9.)(/\\&-]+/g)==-1
i put dash at the end of my string but it is nt working. please help

Comment: Ah, I see. I did not say it was wrong, I was just unsure why you did it.

Comment: @Tomalak forward slash often delimits the beginning and end of regex, so in that case needs to be escaped. In this regex, I don't think backslash needs escaping, as it is not required in the question. I think the backslash was intended to escape the ampersand, not to be a matched character.

Comment: @Billy That the forward slash sometimes needs escaping because is used as a delimiter character is a host language requirement, not a regex requirement. Same goes for the ampersand (regex dialects may vary, but generally neither is a meta character).

Comment: @Tomalak I tried not escaping dots and slashes etc... in firefox javascript, and it was fine. I tend to err on the side of caution, and escape everything as I see no harm in doing so. It also allows to copy/paste regex into any language. I did not know how little needed escaping inside character classes. Every day is a school day.

Comment: @Billy: Re: Erring on the side of caution: I think knowing exactly how a system works its better than having to guess (and sprinking "cautious" backslashes is just that) - especially with something as delicate as regex. That you can port complex regex from one dialect to another without change is an illusion anyway.

Comment: That ampersand (&) does not need to be escaped, and is making this more complex than necessary.  Also, there's a simpler way to express case indifference.  I'd have gone with the more legible .search(/[^a-z0-9.)(/&-]/ig)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
VAL.search(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.()/&-]/g) == -1
```

Comment: The only characters that need to be escaped in a character class are `\ `, `]` (and `^` unless you put it in the middle somewhere).

Comment: @Tomalak and `-` unless it's the last character in the class.